# Is this a Haskell higher order function?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I want to know whether shift is a higher order function or not.

```
chartoInt  :: Char -> Int
chartoInt c  =  ord c 

Inttochar  :: Int -> Char
Inttochar  n   =  chr n

shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift n c  =  Inttochar  (chartoInt c + n)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of these functions are higher order functions, because none of these functions take a function as a parameter.

`shift`'s parameters are `n` (an `Int`) and `c` (a `Char`): neither are functions.

(Also: `Inttochar` should be `inttochar`: function names in Haskell cannot start with an upper case letter.)

---

Here's a higher order function that looks like your `shift`:

```
higherShift :: (Int -> Char) -> Int -> Char -> Char
higherShift f n c = f (chartoInt c + n)

shift = higherShift inttochar   -- same as your original shift
```

Or, perhaps more usefully:

```
anotherHigherShift :: (Int -> Int) -> Char -> Char
anotherHigherShift f c = inttochar (f (chartoInt c))

shift n = anotherHigherShift (+n)   -- same as your original shift
```

You can read the type signature for `anotherHigherShift` as saying that

- it's a function
- whose first parameter is a function (this function takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`)
- whose second parameter is a `Char`
- and which returns a `Char`

`(+n)` is shorthand for `\m -> m + n`.

Comment: so want to know how to change shift function in to higher order function

Comment: @user1150071 to be a higher order function, it has to take a function as an argument (and use it :p).

Comment: Thanks for the help @dave4420 .can you briefly explain your second example anotherHigherShift code.i can't understand what happened there specially this line (Int -> Int) -> Char -> Char and shift n = anotherHigherShift (+n) function

Comment: @dave4420 yep.its clear now.i think higherShift function is more clear than second one.thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

It is.

The shift is a higher order function.

```
shift :: Int -> (Char -> Char) -- The long prototype.
```

It get `Int` and return function getting `Char` and returning `Char`.

P.S.
You should write `inttochar`.

Comment: That doesn't make it a higher order function, as it *returns* a function rather than taking one.

Comment: What is definition of higher order function?

Comment: @Michas A function that merely *returns* a function isn't considered a higher order function in Haskell, because Haskell functions are usually curried. So we say that functions which take other functions as *parameters* are higher order functions.

Comment: Quoting first sentence: A higher-order function is a function that takes other functions as arguments **or returns a function as result**.

Comment: @Michas by constructing a new one; I've never seen that definition be used anywhere (and I believe it was taken from Wikipedia).  So for FP languages, the *useful* definition of a HOF is one that takes another function as a parameter.

Comment: @ivanm You have given me the link to this definition. If You think it is wrong, please edit this tag wiki too http://stackoverflow.com/tags/higher-order-functions/info .

Comment: So I should have read it more thoroughly ;-)  I have never seen anyone use that part of the definition before; as such, my apologies; in the context of Haskell, however, it's a rather trivial and boring aspect :)

Comment: whats your final decision.is my first code  higher order function or not?

Comment: @user1150071 by the technical definition of what "higher-order function" means, it is; by the useful definition that is normally meant when the term is used in Haskell, no.

Comment: Perhaps it would a good idea to distinguish between languages like haskell, that are curried by default, and other languages. In languages like C# it might make sense to explicitly name the class of functions that return another function, since these are relatively rare. In haskell however, this would comprise all functions of more than one argument, so the distinction is not very useful. By the way, good job on the explicit reference to documentation in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

There is informal rule: take a look at function's type. If it contains (with necessity [1]) braces, than it's a higher order function.

[1] In the meaning that omitting them changes the type.

And now take a look at types of your function and functions from first answer from this point of view. It's simple.

Comment: I see your intention, but you expressed it not precise enough, IMHO. Consider `foo :: Maybe (Either Int Char) -> Bool`